# Getting overlap of polygon features on point layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, feature-count, overlapping-features

I have two layers. The first is a point layer with centroid coordinates and the second is overlapping drive time isochrones created by Network Analyst - Service Area. The two images are shown at the end of this message.

**I would like to get the overlap of the isochrones for each centroid/point to create an interpolation map**.

For example, where there are 6 drive time isochrones overlapping a single point vs where there is only one. I have included a mockup of what this should look like as the final image.

I have tried various tools within the ArcGIS Pro suite including 'Find Overlap' and 'Count Overlapping Features', but these seem specific for one layer rather than two separate layers.

[image: Point Layer]

[image: Drive Time Polygon Layer]

[image: Points with counts]

Comment: Perhaps the identity tool is what youre after https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/identity.htm  You should get duplicated points, one for each polygon overlapping which you can then summarize with summary statistics https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/summary-statistics.htm or spatial join https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm which will give you a count of how many polygons overlap (pick any statistic, the count is included).

Comment: As Michael Stimson suggested an overlay would get the data you need.  I typically copied and pasted the table into Excel to run a pivot table (in this case using count) and then joined the result back to the original polygons.

Comment: @MichaelStimson this worked! Can you please submit as the answer?